# Could any attacker download all files in a folder from cloudfront without knowing the file names?

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, amazon-cloudfront

I am considering using Cloudfront for caching some files but those files are kind of assets and I don't want anyone to access them without logging in.

I wonder if I could use long file name (like hash) for the files and only provide the names when user logged in.

A concern is that whether an attacker (or outsider) has the ability to download the folder containing the files without knowing the names.

Edited:
The files are JSON files that the data would be display in a website.

Comment: https://betterprogramming.pub/how-to-restrict-access-to-your-cloudfront-distribution-with-basic-authentication-e2cdae5fca7e

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But this is not a solution for me as the files are actually JSON data that would be used in a website. Couldn't let user type name and pw everytime they have to view the pages.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at using [Signed URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-signed-urls.html) in CloudFront. Each time a user logs in, you generate short-lived URLs for each of the assets the user needs to access on the page. Or if you want it to be dynamic, you can do the same server-side by redirecting logged in users from normal URLs to a dynamically generated signed URLs; users that are not logged in will receive a 403). This ensures they are only accessible to each individual user, and even if the URL is shared they will expire quickly and be inaccessible to others.